# Doxygen external reference ads an extra '.html' to the url

Tags: doxygen

I have a setup with a main project, and an external library, both documented using doxygen.
I use a tag file to link to the external library, almost textbook example.

my tag setting:

```
TAGFILES = ../../../../hal/chip/driverlib/doc/driverlib.doxytags=../../../../../../../hal/chip/driverlib/doc/html
```

The creted path is broken, but I am sure the setting is correct as it is not the path to file that is wrong, but doxygen for some reason ads an extra `.html` to the url so

`file:///C:/foldername/hal/chip/driverlib/doc/html/sysctl_8h.html`

becomes

`file:///C:/foldername/hal/chip/driverlib/doc/html/sysctl_8h.html.html`

I have a vague memory of havong seen this before, but can't find anything.

The setting in the extarnal doxy to generate the tag is like this

```
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = doc/driverlib.doxytags
```

Doxygen version used: 1.9.1 (ef9b20ac7f8a8621fcfc299f8bd0b80422390f4b)

Comment: We have seen this problem as well and by head I think the problem has been solved in the newer versions of doxygen (the current version of doxygen is 1.9.3 (c0b9eafbfb53286ce31e75e2b6c976ee4d345473)). Cab you try this version?

Comment: @albert That fixed it, thanks. If you post as answer I will mark it as the solution.